# Ubuntu Error and Email from Cron?

Tags: php, ubuntu, drupal, cron

I have been trying to figure out whats going on here... I have looked all over and nothing seems like a solid solution.  If anyone knows a link or information on how to fix this it would be greatly appreciated.

Ubuntu 14.04 lts
Microsoft Azure Server
Apache
Drupal site with APC enabled (everything looks good on the drupal side) I just keep getting these annoying emails about the below issue.

I added smtp and mailutils to my server, and now i am getting these errors from what looks like apache / php...

--

Cron  [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -x /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean /var/lib/php5 $(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime)

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20121212/apc.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20121212/apc.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Thanks for the help,
-Frank

Answer (score 1):

These are being generated by the /etc/cron.d/php5 cronjob.  If you want the errors generated here to stop being emailed, you can set mailto="" on the line before the command in that file.  This is probably not your desired solution here, but it is useful to 1) know where you can find where the error is coming from and 2) know how to control its output.

The command generating these errors is likely maxlifetime.  You can confirm this by trying to run /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime and seeing if the same error comes up.

Your apc.so file might be somewhere else.  Try "locate apc.so" to find out where it is.  If it doesn't exist, I would recommend reinstalling the extension so that it does exist.  If it does exist, your /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini file might be having trouble finding it.  A couple solutions I read from other threads had people either creating a symbolic link to to the file (a bit sloppy, but it works) or noticing that "extension_dir=" in php.ini was set to something other than "./" so that it was looking in the wrong place (or the "extension=apc.so" entry itself contained some of the path and had a typo or something).

In my case, my php.ini file was trying to load the extension msql.so which didn't exist on my system.  I don't know why it would do this, but I commented out the line and the error messages went away.  In most cases, though, I would assume the extension was deliberately installed so you would want to go the route of tracking it down or fixing it.

Good luck.